# What exactly is "run()" in python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

python classes in examples usually have a "run()" function.
This started to behave strangely for me.

Example - the following code creates a class as a new process

```
import multiprocessing

class myClass(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("who invoked me!?")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = myClass()                       
    p.start()
```

So we call `start()` (not `run()`) and the output will be

> "who invoked me!?"

This raises the first question - why does it work?

If it was hell then what the heck, but, now the following behavior occurs:

Running from CMD, the python code prints everything fine.

Running the python through another process, (via python-shell in nodejs), the `run()` method never executes and stays hanging.

why? how? thanks.

Comment: Have you look at at the multiprocessing class Process that myClass is extending here, essentially you are overridding the run method of this class with your own version, but the start method will still call the multiprocessing.Process start method

Comment: Take a look at the docs for it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start

Comment: 'python classes in examples usually have a "run()" function'—I don't think this is true.